A recent British indie movie about a sensitive and kind teenage girl and a violent neighbor
Opening scene: The teenage girl is talking with her neighbor's autistic boy while he is washing a car when a violent man (also a neighbor) suddenly arrives and starts beating the boy and accusing him of voyeurism (the man has two slutty teenage daughters)
Another scene: The two girls in the neighborhood throw a party while their father is away, the police arrives
Another scene: The brother of the teenage girl sleeps with one of the neighbor's slutty daughters in an abandoned caravan and the girl finds out
Another scene: The girl has got a crush on a boy who wants to leave the town
Final scene: The teenage girl commits suicide after her father treats her mother badly, the violent neighbor finds her and call an ambulance  

I think you're talking about Broken (2012). I watched it a few months ago and it's pretty much what you described.
The opening scene is in the trailer below :



I don't remember exactly the party scene, but i think there's one in the movie, and something goes wrong with one of the daughter 

(possibly a miscarriage, but i'm not sure)

There's a scene where the girl's brother has intercourse with the neighbor's daughter, the girl finds out and is shocked.
You can see the boy the girl falls in love with in the trailer. He has to leave town but doesn't tell the girl until he actually leaves.
The ending scene is a bit different though, as

it's not the girl's mother who is pushed in the stairs. The boy who is accused of voyeurism pushes his mother down the stairs. The girl doesn't commit suicide, she's deprived of her medication being kept down the house by the boy, and falls into a coma. The violent neighbor finds her.


Thank you so much sebaset, that's the exact movie I was trying to find. And you are right about the ending scene, now I recall that it ends as you described. Thanks for your help :)
